# Remove JSON object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an API from the stock market that returns a JSON object with sub objects the following way

```
Data: {
    10:30: {
        "high": 100
        "low": 80
      }
    10:35: {
        "high": 100
        "low": 80
      }
    10:50: {
        "high": 100
        "low": 80
      }
}
```

My plan is to get the data from the first object (e.g. 10:30), put it at the end of an array, and pass the array to a react-graph.js.

I have tried to copy the first object then delete it from the JSON array of objects but thought `Object.keys(obj).pop()` return the last object it doesn't delete it. This means the next iteration will return the same object and the same data.

I have also tried to get the last object from the array but I have searched for a function that return the last or first object but I did not find any.

Comment: You could splice out the last element of the array. splice(startPosition, deleteCount)

Comment: It does not delete the object. I logged before and after splice, pop, unshift and the objects remain the same.

Comment: Splice will return a new array without the last element

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.entries() to get an array of key/value pairs, then you can shift() (removes first element and assigns to a variable) and create a new object from the entries:

```js
let data = {
    '10:30': {
        "high": 100,
        "low": 80
      },
    '10:35': {
        "high": 100,
        "low": 80
      },
    '10:50': {
        "high": 100,
        "low": 80
      }
};

let entries = Object.entries(data);
let firstProp = entries.shift();
console.log(firstProp);

let newData = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: @StackSlave `Object.entries()` _should_ return the keys / values in definition order. Guarantees about object property ordering have changed in the last couple of years

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(ObjectHere)` returns a new Array with the keys. Acting upon that Array does not affect your `Data` Object... but that's not what you want to do anyways. You want to do like:

```js
const data = {
  "10:30": {
    "high": 100,
    "low": 80
  },
  "10:35": {
    "high": 100,
    "low": 80
  },
  "10:50": {
    "high": 100,
    "low": 80
  }
}
function hiLow(hhmm){
  return {[hhmm]: data[hhmm]};
}
const output = [];
output.push(hiLow('10:30'));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using splice(startPosition, deleteCount).

In your scenario:

```
Object.keys(obj).splice(-1,1)
```

This should return a new array without the last element